# Facebook Connect: "Error occurred with <app> Please try again later"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an iPhone app that's using facebook connect via the [ios-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) to upload videos to facebook.  It's been working fine until today.  Most users are able to upload ok but one particular user gets this dialog first:

[permissions ok](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/803/photo1h.png)

Once he hits ok he gets this dialog:

[error dialog](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/215/photoea.png)

I looked in the diagnostics for any errors and I didn't see any.  The only thing I did notice was under feature requests it says "requests 1.0 - 30" for limit per user per day.  I don't know if a particular user is running up against some limit or something else is going on.

The other interesting thing is that we have a full version and lite version.  He can upload via the lite version but not the full version.  Both versions use the same api calls for uploading videos.

update:  User deleted the app from privacy settings in his facebook account.  Then the app re-authorized and it all worked.

How did it get into this state?  Is there a way to detect via the IOS app and resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally Facebook will return that error and most of the time (for me) there is nothing I can do to fix it except try again.

This error happens to me not only in this similar situation but also everywhere like Feed Dialog, Request Dialog, etc...

I'm pretty sure it's Facebook server error.